# Oracle OEM Surpressing Warning Messages

Tags: oracle

We are trying to stop having a certain warning message emailed to us. The specific error is a ORA 600 - 17183 and 17302. We have been told by Oracle that we can ignore these warnings as they are a bug in Oracle 12.0.1.2 and are patched in the next version.

Currently we are running OEM 12.1.0.3.0 and are upgrading soon to 12.1.0.5.0. We have done research online to try and figure out the correct regex expression to ignore the above mentioned codes in the Alert log but to no avail. This is what we currently have to try and ignore the 17302 message in the Metric Collection Settings > Generic Alert Log Error:

```
.*ORA-0*(54|1142|1146)\D.*|.*ORA-00600:.*\[17302[^\]]*\].*
```

Any ideas/thoughts why this wouldn't work to suppress the emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else with the issue, I contacted Oracle Support and they gave me the following regex string to add-in and it worked:

```
.*ORA-0*(600|54|1142|1146)\D.*|[17(302|183)[^\]]*\].*
```